# How to check balance on a specific date

Tags: blockexplorer

I need my XTZ balance for a specific date in past. I am not sure how to get this as most blockexplorers do not offer a date field for searching historical
balances. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get historical balance (at the specified datetime or block level) via [TzKT API](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Accounts_GetBalanceAtDate).

Examples:

- [/v1/accounts/{address}/balance_history/2020-01-01](https://api.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/KT1BrFQdx8wdwaFEAZsNWAD1epv6i3aEZxJy/balance_history/2020-01-01)
- [/v1/accounts/{address}/balance_history/2019-05-16T23:14:01Z](https://api.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/KT1BrFQdx8wdwaFEAZsNWAD1epv6i3aEZxJy/balance_history/2019-05-16T23:14:01Z)

Answer (score 1):

The baking bad block explorer lets you filter by date, by clicking the calendar icon: https://tzkt.io/

Paste the address you are interested in, into the search bar, then filter by date

[image]